# Global Variable - AJAX jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, global

I'm trying to set the global variable *countryCode*. But the value is always null. What can I do? I tried many ways. PLS HELP!

```
function GetGeolocation(){

  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?",function(data){
  $.each(data, function(k, v) {
    table_body += "<tr><td>" + k + ": " + "</td><td><b>" + v + "</b></td></tr>";

      if (k == "countryCode")
      {
          SetGeolocation(v);
      }
    })             
  }); 
}

function SetGeolocation(value){

  countryCode = value;
  console.log(countryCode); //Value
}

function Result(){
  console.log(countyCode); //Null
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  GetGeolocation();
  Result();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've made `countryCode` a global variable. You could try replacing `countryCode` with `window.countryCode` whenever it is used to make it a global variable

Comment: Try adding `var countryCode;` above the first function to set it as a global.

Comment: @user1063998 countryCode is a global variable. If you don't declare a variable with var in js - it is global. The fact it's value is Null but not undefined proves this.

Comment: Where is `function Result()` being called?  Is it after the other functions have run?

Comment: When are you calling `Result()`? `SetGeolocation()` is probably firing after.. in the ajax callback. Call `Result()` right after `SetGeolocation()` in your `if` block

Comment: Result() is called after the GetGeolocation() method in the document ready function

Comment: Have you waited for the ajax call to finish before calling Result()? It is a asynchronous you know...

Comment: The AJAX call happens asynchronously. So it might not be done by the time `Result()` is called. Try calling `Result()` at the end of `SetGeoLocation` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, a variable which has been declared without `var` keyword inside a function becomes global **only** after function's call.

Consider this:

```
function foo(){
    bar = 123;
}

// Reference error - bar is undefined
console.log(bar);
```

Now before testing `bar` variable, let's call the `foo` function.

```
function foo(){
    bar = 123;
}

foo();

// 123
console.log(bar);
```

You got it? Right? Good.
As for your code, the error is pretty obvious `countryCode` is `undefined` just because you didn't call `SetGeolocation()` before. To make it work as you expect you need somehow call `SetGeolocation()` before you call `Result()`.

But don't do this seriously. Global variables is well-known what not to do thing. Consider passing a variable as a dependency instead

Comment: i tried to call the function `Result()` in `SetGeolocation()` and it worked! thx!!